# Creating a matrix from a column and a row

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most elegant way to multiply a column and a row together to make a matrix.

I want to take two series and make a dataframe from them with the length of one series and the width of another.
In this case I want to multiply the two.

```
sr1 = 
0     2
1     3     
2     4

sr2 = 
0         0
1        10
2        100
3        50
```

Desired result: a dataframe where sr1 = y axis, sr2 = x axis

```
0   20   200   100
0   30   300   150
0   40   400   200
```

Is there a simple function in pandas or something similar that does this without first repeating a series as columns in a df and then multiplying?

Comment: Can you try `df= sr1 * sr2.to_frame().T`? And tell me if it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `numpy.multiply.outer`

```
import numpy as np 

df=pd.DataFrame(np.multiply.outer(sr1.values,sr2.values))
Out[11]: 
   0   1    2    3
0  0  20  200  100
1  0  30  300  150
2  0  40  400  200
```

Answer (score 3):

Use broadcasting

```
pd.DataFrame(s2.values * s1.values[:,None])

Out[585]:
   0   1    2    3
0  0  20  200  100
1  0  30  300  150
2  0  40  400  200
```